# ProcessBuilder environment variable in java

Tags: java, unix, processbuilder

I'm trying to add a environment variable for a ProcessBuilder object but then when I call on that new variable in the ProcessBuilder I get an error.
this is how I build the Process

```
public class OTU
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder();
        Map<String, String> env = pb.environment();
        //set environment variable u
        env.put("u", "util/");

        pb.command("echo $u");
        Process p = pb.start();
        String output = loadStream(p.getInputStream());
        String error  = loadStream(p.getErrorStream());
        int rc = p.waitFor();
        System.out.println("Process ended with rc=" + rc);
        System.out.println("\nStandard Output:\n");
        System.out.println(output);
        System.out.println("\nStandard Error:\n");
        System.out.println(error);
    }

    private static String loadStream(InputStream s) throws Exception
    {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        while((line=br.readLine()) != null)
            sb.append(line).append("\n");
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

I get the error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "$u": java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:475)
    at ca.utoronto.siseq_1_2.OTU.main(OTU.java:22)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:164)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:81)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:468)
    ... 1 more
```

I dont understand why I am getting the error if I just set the variable for this Process.
Please help me how to set the env variable so I can use it in the ProcessBuilder.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Alfredo O's example gives you the right idea. You need to tell the ProcessBuilder what program to use to execute your command. In this case [bash with the "-c" switch](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash), which tells bash to interpret what comes next (i.e. "echo  $u") as a command.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Map;

public class OTU {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("/bin/bash", "-c", "echo $u");
        Map<String, String> env = pb.environment();
        // set environment variable u
        env.put("u", "util/");

        Process p = pb.start();
        String output = loadStream(p.getInputStream());
        String error = loadStream(p.getErrorStream());
        int rc = p.waitFor();
        System.out.println("Process ended with rc=" + rc);
        System.out.println("\nStandard Output:\n");
        System.out.println(output);
        System.out.println("\nStandard Error:\n");
        System.out.println(error);
    }

    private static String loadStream(InputStream s) throws Exception {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
            sb.append(line).append("\n");
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

This produces the following output:

```
Process ended with rc=0

Standard Output:

util/


Standard Error:
```

Comment: prefix for windows platform : `cmd /c ...`  
prefix for unix platform : `sh -c ...`

Answer (score 5):

This works for me in Windows:

```
@Test
public void testProcessBuilder() throws IOException {
    ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe", "/C", "echo Hello %name%");
    Map<String, String> environment = processBuilder.environment();
    environment.put("name", "Alfredo Osorio");
    Process p = processBuilder.start();
    String line;
    BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
    while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
    }
    r.close();
}
```

**Output:**

Hello Alfredo Osorio

As you can see in Windows you use the %environmentVariable% instead of the $environementVariable

Comment: Is there a way to make this cross os?

Comment: +1 for the pointing him in the right direction, albeit not explaining why it works - you've told Java to execute cmd.exe.