# Java ProcessBuilder and Windows system variables

Tags: java, windows, processbuilder

I want to execute a program within Java with a path 
that is defined by a custom system variable ("CHROME").

```
new ProcessBuilder("CHROME").start();
```

Win7:
works fine (points to AppData\Local)

Win Vista: 
does nothing (points to program files)

What do I need to do, to get it running with Vista?

Comment: `new ProcessBuilder("CHROME").start();`  That is a very simple way to start a `Process`.  Unfortunately, combine 'simple' & 'process' & it will generally fail.  See [this article](http://www.javaworld.com/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html) & ignore the fact it has 'Runtime.exex()' in the title - the advice all applies to `ProcessBuilder` just as much.  Implement all the recommendations, and if that itself does not solve the problem, at least it will provide useful info.  Use [`redirectErrorStream()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#redirectErrorStream%28%29).

Comment: this was only my minimal code example, I actually use a list of parameters, set working path and so on ... don't worry ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, CHROME is a system variable which contains the path to an application. If so, you can try as

```
String path = System.getenv("CHROME");
new ProcessBuilder(path).start();
```

or

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(path);
```

Comment: I'll try that but I will need to do some parsing first since getenv is optional :(

Answer (score 0):

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11198858/315306) is suggested to run the program from `cmd.exe`, ie

```
new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe", "%CHROME%");
```

this should work as long as `%CHROME%` is in the environmente that the main Java program passes to the subprocess.

Comment: I already tried that before and don't like this solution since you can't terminate or waitFor the started process. I also tried batch files....